# C# Хранение конфиденциальных данных

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Здравствуйте! Наткнулся на проблему хранения различных токенов/паролей и тп. в открытом репозитории на Github. Хотелось бы положить некоторые конфиденциальные данные(токены,клиентские id, пароли) в какой-нибудь файл и зашифровать/(или же что-то вроде конфигурационного файла, который я добавлю в git ignore). Вопросы:  **Как это принято делать в современном мире?** **С помощью чего файлы принято шифровать и тп. (Сертификаты, ключи?)**.Я наслышан про ivi, json и xml форматы файлов для хранения настроек и тп. Но хотелось было услышать мнение более опытных людей. P.S Особенно интересует, как с этим дело обстоит в .Net Core, сейчас активно юзаю. Сорян за возможную несвязность, не сплю почти. Спасибо!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12657970

Comment: Ну так а не храните их в открытом доступе. Сделайте их читаемыми из конфигурационного файла, например, и не выкладывайте боевую версию файла в репозиторий.

Comment: @VladD топикастер и не собирается пароли это в репозиторий. Просто в том же .net core есть родные средства для работы с user secrets, например https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, но я бы хотел увидеть ответ в виде информации о принятых сейчас способах и методах хранения. :)

Answer (score 1):

Один из простейших вариантов - при запуске приложения требовать ввести пароль от контейнера/хранилища ключей (и при необходимости сертификата) с приватным ключом, установленного на клиенте/машине разработчика, в котором хранятся ключи шифрования. В программе реализовать удобное для работы шифрование всех чувствительных данных при записи в файлы/хранилища и дешифровке при считывании. В самой же программе эти данные уже будут использоваться в чистом виде.

Таким образом в случае выгрузки исходников даже с записанными (зашифрованными) данными во внешнюю среду - требуется ключ и пароль для того, чтобы получить возможность дешифровки.